# malloc/struct pointer array seg fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have this code below, includes and other functions which are called in `main` are correct. But when I am trying to `malloc` the `words[counter]->input_str`, I get a segmentation fault all the time. I don't know what to do.

```
    struct copy {
        char *input_str;
        char *create_word;
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        static struct copy *words[ARRAY_SIZE];
        char format_str[20];
        char word_str[STR_SIZE];
        int how_many;
        int counter = 0;
        char answer;

        do{

            sprintf(format_str," %%%ds",STR_SIZE - 1);
            printf("Enter string: ");
            scanf(format_str,word_str);


            words[counter]->input_str = (char *)malloc((strlen(word_str) + 1)*sizeof(char));
            if(words[counter]->input_str == NULL) {
                printf("memory problem\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            words[counter]->input_str = word_str;

            printf("Enter integer: ");
            scanf(" %d",&how_many);

            words[counter]->create_word = duplicate(word_str,how_many);
            counter++;
            if(words[counter - 1] == NULL) {
                printf("error\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            print(words,counter);

            do{
                printf("More (y/n)? ");
                scanf(" %c",&answer);
            }while(answer != 'y' && answer != 'n');


        }while(counter < ARRAY_SIZE && answer == 'y');

        clean(words,counter);

        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: In `words[counter]->input_str = word_str;` you are overwriting the pointer just obtained from `malloc`. Did you mean to use `strcpy(words[counter]->input_str, word_str)`?

Comment: Well done for using `sprintf(format_str," %%%ds",STR_SIZE - 1);` to create the correct `scanf()` format string which avoids buffer overflows on input.  However, you could do that just once, outside the `do { … } while (…)` loop, rather than on each iteration.  You should check the return value from each call to `scanf()` to ensure you got the expected result, handling unexpected results appropriately.

Comment: seg fault is happening while i am in malloc.

Comment: You use `malloc()` to set `words[counter]->input_str`; you then use `words[counter]->input_str = word_str;` to leak the allocated memory.  In C, you must use `strcpy()` or something similar to copy strings around.  Or use the POSIX function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) to duplicate a string.  As it stands, the next input to `word_str` wipes out the previous input saved in `words`.

Comment: You 're right, but can explain this to me? What happened,before allocating memory to words[counter]?

Comment: You have `static struct copy *words[ARRAY_SIZE];` at the top of `main()`.  You really don't need the `static`; the array will last as long as `main()` is executing anyway.  And you really don't need the pointer; you'd be better off with an array of the structures: `struct copy words[ARRAY_SIZE];`.  As it stands, you have an extra level on indirection that isn't self-evidently necessary, and which does complicate the necessary code.  Of course, you'd then use `word[counter].input_str` instead of `word[counter]->input_str` to access elements of the structures in the array.

Comment: Note that we can't easily run your code; it references `duplicate()` and `clean()` functions for which you don't show an implementation.  Creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) involves pruning away the code that's unnecessary to reproduce your problem (that's the 'minimal' part) and providing the code that is necessary (that's the 'complete' part)  The discipline of creating the MCVE often helps you resolve the problem without asking it.

Comment: `words[counter]->input_str = word_str;` words is an array of *uninitialized* pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two versions of your code,one using `struct copy *words[ARRAY_SIZE];` at the top of `main()`, the other using `struct copy words[ARRAY_SIZE];` (which therefore does less memory allocation).

#### Array of pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct copy
{
    char *input_str;
    char *create_word;
};

enum { ARRAY_SIZE = 20, STR_SIZE = 30 };

extern char *duplicate(const char *str, int number);
extern void print(struct copy **words, int number);
extern void clean(struct copy **words, int number);

int main(void)
{
    struct copy *words[ARRAY_SIZE];
    char format_str[20];
    char word_str[STR_SIZE];
    int how_many;
    int counter = 0;
    char answer;
    sprintf(format_str, " %%%ds", STR_SIZE - 1);

    do
    {
        printf("Enter string: ");
        if (scanf(format_str, word_str) != 1)
            break;

        printf("Enter integer: ");
        if (scanf(" %d", &how_many) != 1 || how_many < 0 || how_many > 999)
            break;

        words[counter] = malloc(sizeof(*words[counter]));
        words[counter]->input_str = (char *)malloc((strlen(word_str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (words[counter]->input_str == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "memory problem\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        strcpy(words[counter]->input_str, word_str);

        words[counter]->create_word = duplicate(word_str, how_many);
        // Superfluous because duplicate exits if there is an allocation error
        if (words[counter]->create_word == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        counter++;
        print(words, counter);

        do
        {
            printf("More (y/n)? ");
            if (scanf(" %c", &answer) != 1)
            {
                answer = 'n';
                break;
            }
        } while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n');
    } while (counter < ARRAY_SIZE && answer == 'y');

    clean(words, counter);

    return(0);
}

void print(struct copy **words, int number)
{
    printf("Words (%d):\n", number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        printf("[%s] => [%s]\n", words[i]->input_str, words[i]->create_word);
}

char *duplicate(const char *str, int number)
{
    int len1 = strlen(str);
    int len2 = number * len1 + 1;
    char *space = malloc(len2);
    if (space == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed for %d bytes\n", len2);
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        strcpy(&space[i * len1], str);
    space[len2 - 1] = '\0';     // In case number == 0
    return space;
}

void clean(struct copy **words, int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        free(words[i]->input_str);
        free(words[i]->create_word);
        free(words[i]);
        words[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

#### Array of structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct copy
{
    char *input_str;
    char *create_word;
};

enum { ARRAY_SIZE = 20, STR_SIZE = 30 };

extern char *duplicate(const char *str, int number);
extern void print(struct copy *words, int number);
extern void clean(struct copy *words, int number);

int main(void)
{
    struct copy words[ARRAY_SIZE];
    char format_str[20];
    char word_str[STR_SIZE];
    int how_many;
    int counter = 0;
    char answer;
    sprintf(format_str, " %%%ds", STR_SIZE - 1);

    do
    {
        printf("Enter string: ");
        if (scanf(format_str, word_str) != 1)
            break;

        words[counter].input_str = (char *)malloc((strlen(word_str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (words[counter].input_str == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "memory problem\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        strcpy(words[counter].input_str, word_str);

        printf("Enter integer: ");
        if (scanf(" %d", &how_many) != 1 || how_many < 0 || how_many > 999)
            break;

        words[counter].create_word = duplicate(word_str, how_many);
        // Superfluous because duplicate exits if there is an allocation error
        if (words[counter].create_word == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        counter++;
        print(words, counter);

        do
        {
            printf("More (y/n)? ");
            if (scanf(" %c", &answer) != 1)
            {
                answer = 'n';
                break;
            }
        } while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n');
    } while (counter < ARRAY_SIZE && answer == 'y');

    clean(words, counter);

    return(0);
}

void print(struct copy *words, int number)
{
    printf("Words (%d):\n", number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        printf("[%s] => [%s]\n", words[i].input_str, words[i].create_word);
}

char *duplicate(const char *str, int number)
{
    int len1 = strlen(str);
    int len2 = number * len1 + 1;
    char *space = malloc(len2);
    if (space == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed for %d bytes\n", len2);
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        strcpy(&space[i * len1], str);
    space[len2 - 1] = '\0';     // In case number == 0
    return space;
}

void clean(struct copy *words, int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        free(words[i].input_str);
        free(words[i].create_word);
        words[i].input_str = words[i].create_word = NULL;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter string: abc
Enter integer: 1
Words (1):
[abc] => [abc]
More (y/n)? y
Enter string: def
Enter integer: 2
Words (2):
[abc] => [abc]
[def] => [defdef]
More (y/n)? y
Enter string: absolute-twaddle
Enter integer: 10
Words (3):
[abc] => [abc]
[def] => [defdef]
[absolute-twaddle] => [absolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddle]
More (y/n)? y
Enter string: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Enter integer: 0
Words (4):
[abc] => [abc]
[def] => [defdef]
[absolute-twaddle] => [absolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddleabsolute-twaddle]
[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ] => []
More (y/n)? n
```

(Either program gives the same output for the same input.  Both run clean under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) — a site which still does not support `https` connections.)

Comment: I guess "twaddle" is shorter than "poppycock" or "ishkabibble".